# Nuget references not found

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I cloned a project called "xyz frontEnd" from git, and my nuget packages were checked in. However, the project didn't build in VS 2015, or from the command line, and Visual Studio couldn't find the referenced files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the spaces in the path were breaking the build. Getting rid of the spaces, and all the references were fixed, and the project built. I think it had to do with inconsistent escaping of spaces in the path ("%20" vs " ")

Lesson learned: don't use spaces in project paths when using nuget.